# objective c How to set UserInteractionEnabled:NO for the entire view except on UIButton in that view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uibutton, user-interaction

In my application i have a view 
in that i have many UIElements, buttons, etc..

I need to set

**UserInteractionEnabled:NO for all the ui elements in that view *`except`* one button.**

I tried with

```
 [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

The Require button also the subview that self.view that button also apply same behavior.

I can able to apply individually but it is not a good way.

**How should i set UserInteractionEnabled:NO for all the other ui elements *`except one`* button**

Answer (score 3):

```
for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews])
    {
        if (view.tag==101)
            [ view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        else
            [ view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
    if (!([view class]==[UIButton class]) )
    {
        view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have multiple buttons, give tags to your button & filter out the required Button at IF condition

Answer (score 1):

You can just add transparent subview in the front of your view and place button on this transparent view:

```
UIView* maskView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
maskView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.view addSubview:maskView];
[maskView addSubview:buttonView];
```

And be sure that this transparent view is the last added subview, or just push it to the front of view in *viewWillAppear*:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:maskView];
```